# "No commits yet" versus expected "Initial commit"

Tags: git

I am currently working through David Demaree's book "Git for Humans" from the "A Book Apart" series.
I am using windows 7 and Git Bash to follow along.

So far, I have followed along with the following steps:

On my desktop, I have made a directory:

```
$: mkdir our-website
```

I then cd'ing into the "our-website" directory context... following the instructions I ran 'git init':

```
$: git init
```

The output that I got was as expected according to the book:

```
$: git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/our-website/.git/
```

At this point, everything is fine, and it matches up...
Though after entering the next command (`git status`) as outlined in the book my output from Git Bash is different.

Here's what I get:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        index.html

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

This doesn't match up with the expected output that is presented in the book, which is:

```
(master *) $: git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# index.html
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
(use "git add" to track)
```

As you can see the line in my output in the first example state "No commits yet"... while the output in the book example states "Initial commit".

I was wondering why this is. Maybe this is a small inconsequential concern, but I'm not sure. I'd appreciate any help in understanding this. Thanks.

Comment: The book is incorrect. There are no commits if you have not made any.

Comment: "Initial commit" means they did `git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit"`

Answer (score 2):

`git status` is a  convenience command, it changes as the devs find better ways, and it used to say `Initial commit` when there wasn't a commit yet.  It was changed about five years ago, for Git 2.14, to its current text.

I found this by saying `git log --grep 'Initial commit'`, and then `git describe --contains 7e46f19a`, in the git history.

Comment: Oh okay... thanks for the answer. The book is just a bit dated then. I see... appreciate it. And that's some nifty detective work there too btw. Thanks